# Can't connect to S3 folder with boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to write to file to One S3 folder (inside some bucket i don't have permission but know the name)

I was shared with the file with access key secret key and folder name.

I can access the folder with security key and access key in `cloudberry` software.

But when i am trying to connect through `boto3` it's giving

> `Access Denied exception`

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="XXXX",
    aws_secret_access_key="XXXXX",
)
s3_other = session.client('s3')
response = s3_other.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket='XXXXX',
        Prefix ='XXXX',
        MaxKeys=100)
```

I tried changing bucket name adding prefix etc, But same error every time. How can i directly access only folder with boto3?

Comment: You have access denied for a specific action, such as PutObject?

Comment: yes, but it is evident that session is creating at root level, so how we can access directly folder?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say that you wish to write a file, but "i don't have permission", yet you can access it with Cloudberry? What permissions do you have? Are they for listing, or writing? A good way to test permissions is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), such as `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/folder/`